# Unable to copy file C:\SomePath\Myfile.dll to bin\Myfile.dll Access to the path bin\Myfile.dll is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We just converted a VS 2008 project to VS 2010. The conversion showed no errors. Now, when building the solution. We get the following errors:

Unable to copy file C:\TI\Project\SharedAssemblies\Myfile.dll to bin\Myfile.dll Access to the path bin\Myfile.dll is denied

ANOTHER PROBLEM:

I have another problem too! One of my project is referencing a project DLL and that DLL does not exist. I tried to build the solution but that project is never building because it stops whenever there is error on any other project.

**UPDATE 2:**

So, instead of using the ported VS 2008 to VS 2010 solution I just opened the VS 2008 solution in VS 2010 and some of the errors have gone away. Now, I am left with couple of errors in which one of them is the following:

Error   1   Could not load referenced assembly "C:\MyProject\bin\JobManager.dll".  Caught a FileNotFoundException saying "Could not load file or assembly 'C:\MyProject\bin\JobManager.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.".    C:\MyProject\ResGen

What kind of resources the resgen is trying to build and where is it located?

Comment: Is it a reference or the project dll itself? If its a reference to some library, did you try to add it again?

Comment: It is a project dll and I tried adding it again but still no success!

Comment: Try exiting VS, deleting (or moving) that DLL, and then compile again.

Comment: Tried that did not work!

Comment: What is the value of 'SomePath'? Perhaps that will shed some light on your problem.

Comment: @Bernard, Just edited the question to include the path.

Comment: @azamsharp: Are you referencing DLL files in this 'SharedAssemblies' folder? What assemblies are located in this folder? Why are they considered "shared"?

Comment: @Bernard, Those assemblies are created by some custom project. This solution worked in 2008 but after the port to VS 2010 everything is messed up!

Comment: @azamsharp: Hmmm...I cannot be sure that this "custom project" is the problem, but it's possible. Do you have any pre- or post-build events setup in your solution? Have you tried creating a new solution and adding all of the necessary projects into it?

Answer (score 1):

One common cause that I've encountered is that a unit test has the assembly loaded (like in NUnit) and that is blocking the copy.  Closing NUnit, for example, clears the problem.  Check for something similar that's holding on to the assembly.

Comment: I do not have any nUnit project or assembly!

Comment: NUnit was merely an example of a program that could have the assembly loaded and be responsible for the error message in the first part of your question.

Comment: @azamsharp I agree with @Mike Chess; there _has_ to be something that's locking the dll. Find out what it is and kill it, and then you shouldn't have any further issues. You could use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to track what's holding onto the file.

Comment: The problem only came when the VS 2008 was migrated to VS 2010!

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the file from bin folder and everything start working

might be it help you!